# 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in ANN from scratch

Tags: python, list, neural-network

I have been exercising in building a simple NN from scratch and I am having the following recurrent issue with the code below.

1. This first part of the code initializes my network, 'network' with two hidden layers and two nodes in each layer with one output.

```
import numpy as np
n = 2
num_hidden_layers = 2
m = [2, 2]
num_nodes_output = 1
num_nodes_previous = n
network = {}

for layer in range(num_hidden_layers + 1):
    
    if layer == num_hidden_layers:
        layer_name = 'output'
        num_nodes = num_nodes_output
    else:
        layer_name = 'layer_{}'.format(layer + 1)
        num_nodes = m[layer]
        
        
    network[layer_name] = {}
    for node in range(num_nodes):
        node_name = 'node_{}'.format(node + 1)
        network[layer_name][node_name] = {
            'weights':np.around(np.random.uniform(size = num_nodes_previous), decimals = 2),
            'bias':np.around(np.random.uniform(size = 1), decimals = 2)
        }
        
    num_nodes_previous = num_nodes

print(network)
print('\n')
```

2. I, then, define the parameter of the network.

```
def initialize_network(num_inputs, num_hidden_layers, num_nodes_hidden, num_output):
    
    num_nodes_previous = num_inputs
    network = {}
    
    for layer in range(num_hidden_layers + 1):
        
        if layer == num_hidden_layers:
            layer_name = 'output'
            num_nodes = num_nodes_output
        else:
            layer_name = 'layer_{}'.format(layer + 1)
            num_nodes = num_nodes_hidden
        
        network[layer_name] = {}
        for node in range(num_nodes):
            node_name = 'node_{}'.format(node + 1)
            network[layer_name][node_name] = {
                'weights':np.around(np.random.uniform(size = num_nodes_previous), decimals = 2),
                'bias':np.around(np.random.uniform(size = 1), decimals = 2)
            }
        
        num_nodes_previous = num_nodes

    return network
```

3. I then set the inputs and initiate forward propagation so that the output of the first layer becomes the input of the second layer.

```
from random import seed
np.random.seed(12)
inputs = np.around(np.random.uniform(size=5), decimals=2)
print('The inputs to the network are {}'.format(inputs))
print('\n')

def compute_weighted_sum(inputs, weights, bias):
    return np.sum(inputs * weights) + bias

def node_activation():
    1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-1 * compute_weighted_sum))
    return 

def forward_propagation(network, inputs):
    
    layer_inputs = list(inputs)
    for layer in network:
        layer_data = network[layer]
        layer_outputs = []
        
        for layer_node in layer_data:
            node_data = layer_data[layer_node]
            node_output = node_activation(computed_weighted_sum(layer_inputs, node_data['weights'], node_data['bias']))
            layer_outputs.append(np.around(node_output[0], decimals = 4))       
            
        if layer != 'output':
            print('The output of the nodes in the hidden layer number {} is {}'.format(layer.split('_')[1], layer_outputs))
        layer_inputs = layer_outputs
    
    network_predictions = layer_outputs
    return network_predictions

my_net = initialize_network(5, 2, [3, 2], 1)
prediction = forward_propagation(my_net, inputs)
```

And I am having this as error in the second part of my code for the forward propagation:

```
{'layer_1': {'node_1': {'weights': array([0.22, 0.26]), 'bias': array([0.17])}, 'node_2': {'weights': array([0.11, 0.65]), 'bias': array([0.18])}}, 'layer_2': {'node_1': {'weights': array([0.33, 0.66]), 'bias': array([0.01])}, 'node_2': {'weights': array([0.04, 0.74]), 'bias': array([0.45])}}, 'output': {'node_1': {'weights': array([0.64, 0.9 ]), 'bias': array([0.25])}}}


The inputs to the network are [0.15 0.74 0.26 0.53 0.01]


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5ae0b4d7d449> in <module>
     89     return network_predictions
     90 
---> 91 my_net = initialize_network(5, 2, [3, 2], 1)
     92 prediction = forward_propagation(my_net, inputs)

<ipython-input-1-5ae0b4d7d449> in initialize_network(num_inputs, num_hidden_layers, num_nodes_hidden, num_output)
     46 
     47         network[layer_name] = {}
---> 48         for node in range(num_nodes):
     49             node_name = 'node_{}'.format(node + 1)
     50             network[layer_name][node_name] = {

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Many thanks for any resolution!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a little piece according to your first snippet of code:

```
def initialize_network(num_inputs, num_hidden_layers, num_nodes_hidden, num_output):
    
    num_nodes_previous = num_inputs
    network = {}
    
    for layer in range(num_hidden_layers + 1):
        
        if layer == num_hidden_layers:
            layer_name = 'output'
            num_nodes = num_nodes_output
        else:
            layer_name = 'layer_{}'.format(layer + 1)
            num_nodes = num_nodes_hidden[layer] # <----|| HERE!!! ||------
        
        network[layer_name] = {}
        for node in range(num_nodes):
            node_name = 'node_{}'.format(node + 1)
            network[layer_name][node_name] = {
                'weights':np.around(np.random.uniform(size = num_nodes_previous), decimals = 2),
                'bias':np.around(np.random.uniform(size = 1), decimals = 2)
            }
        
        num_nodes_previous = num_nodes

    return network
```

Also in the `forward_propagation` I would be careful because you are converting the `network` (which is a `dict`) to a `list` and the order is based on keys and this might not be the same as the order of the layers in the network... (In this case maybe it does, but it's just a coincidence). Maybe use the integer id of the layer as a key so that you can iterate through the layers in order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am still having some trouble with the ```forward_propagation```part indeed. I'll look into that and report back!

Comment: @SalvishG. Ok, let me know. In the meantime if my answer solved your problem you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Still looking into that.